# Are Scala's `AnyVal`s stack allocated?

Tags: scala

Are Scala `AnyVal` and its subclasses [can be] stack allocated [like C# structs or Java primitives]? And can we make a customized stack allocated variable like C#'s structs on Scala?

Comment: Do keep in mind that `object x = (object)1` is "heap-allocated" in C#. I suspect the same happens for an unspecialized `AnyVal` ..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AnyVal` subclasses are stack allocated, where possible. The exception happens with newer user-created classes that extend `AnyVal` on 2.10.0, if the object escapes the scope.

`Any` and `AnyVal` will be stored on the heap... unless you `@specialized`.

Comment: I couldn't find out what will @specialize do and couldn't make a user-created class that extend AnyVal, can you help me please? :)

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi What I said is confusing indeed. You don't specialize traits and classes, you specialize type parameters. That is, you could have a `class C[@specialized T]`, which will create specialized versions of `C` for `AnyVal` subclasses.

Comment: Oh, so they will act like C++ templates? And sorry I am asking again, is there some ways in Scala to have customized stack allocated values like C#'s structs?

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi Specialized is not quite like templates. For one thing, all specialized classes are pre-compiled. And there's no "structs"-like feature, though Scala 2.10 allows classes that extend `AnyVal`, with some restrictions, which give some of the benefits of C# structs -- such as stack allocation for method-local vars.

Comment: What's the story as of Scala 2.11 and 2.12?

Answer (score 14):

A.scala:

```
class A {
  val a: AnyVal = 1
  val b: Int = 1
}
```

scalac A.scala

javap -c A

```
public class A extends java.lang.Object implements scala.ScalaObject{
 public java.lang.Object a();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #13; //Field a:Ljava/lang/Object;
   4:   areturn

 public int b();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   getfield        #16; //Field b:I
   4:   ireturn

 public A();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #22; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   aload_0
   5:   iconst_1
   6:   invokestatic    #28; //Method scala/runtime/BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
   9:   putfield        #13; //Field a:Ljava/lang/Object;
   12:  aload_0
   13:  iconst_1
   14:  putfield        #16; //Field b:I
   17:  return
}
```

So explicit AnyVal usage leads to boxed primitive on the heap, as expected.

Comment: What happens if you `@specialize` `a`?

Answer (score 3):

I'm also new to Scala, but AFAIK, a Scala variable can not contain an actual object. It can at most contain a *reference* to an object. (You get a reference from `new` and there's no dereference operator to *follow* that reference to an object (such as `*` in C++ for instance).)

In other words, all non-primitive values live on the heap. (Just as in Java.)

Comment: But there be magic for `Int`, `Float`, etc. So, the question is then, if `var x: Int = 1` is done using `int` in Java, how is `var x: AnyVal = maybeIntOrFloat()` done? :)

Comment: @pst, haha. Let me know if you want me to post it as a question ;-)

Comment: Scala doesn't have primitives. Everything in Scala is an object, and some objects happen not to leave on the heap, such as `Int` and `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

The JVM does not support reification of generics and provides no means of having a primitive super type for all primitive types. Thus a field or parameter of type `AnyVal` will always be of type `java.lang.Object` in the byte code and boxing/unboxing will be performed.

This does not necessarily mean that the value is stored on the heap though as the JVM may perform certain optimizations. You have to still expect a runtime penalty though.